# django postgresql password authentication failed for user

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

TL;DR manage migrate fails but manage dbshell works.

This is a dockerized dev environment on OSX10.6, boot2docker with django 1.8.4 and postgresql 9.4.4.

/manage.py migrate throws:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "xxxxx"
```

but here's the bit that confuses me, django dbshell works, copy and pasting the password out of the environment variable

```
root@df6501ab7341:/src/web# ./manage.py dbshell
Password for user xxxxx: 
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

xxxxx=# \du
                               List of roles
  Role name   |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
--------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 xxxxx      | Superuser                                     +| {}
              | Password valid until infinity                  | 
 mpasysuser01 |                                                | {}
 postgres     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

xxxxx=#
```

Django settings are:

```
# Database Configuration
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'   : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME'     : os.environ.get('DATABASE_ENV_POSTGRES_USER'    , ''),  # the database name is the same as the dbo username
        #ToDo Use unprivileged database user
        # 'USER'     : os.environ.get('DATABASE_ENV_UNPRIVILEGED_SQL_USER', ''),
        'USER'     : os.environ.get('DATABASE_ENV_POSTGRES_USER', ''),
        'PASSWORD' : os.environ.get('DATABASE_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD', ''),
        'HOST'     : os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR'   , ''),
        'PORT'     : os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT'   , ''),
    },
}
```

and the database logs show:

```
database_1 | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "xxxxx"
database_1 | DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"
```

Comment: Why not try to print the variable and see whats going on?

Comment: good idea. printing password from inside settings.py checks out as expected.

Comment: If error does not get triggered try on shell (not dbshell) `from django.conf import settings` `settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']`. Or just hardcode it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @LaraChicago, that got me moving. Root cause was somewhere in linux user level and su. Top tip for others banging heads, when debugging linked containers, make sure you pass a name alias to the --link parameter i.e --link  c126ff7b1d28:DATABASE

Comment: did your password happen to contain a $ sign, i think im seeing a problem with this

Answer (score 3):

I second what @larconda said.

I was racking my brain and decided to print by:

1. Open the shell
2. import os
3. print(your variable here)

That should provide some input - it turned out to be a missing space for me.